# App crashes when creating new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm starting the activity from the menu:

```
if (id == R.id.action_debug_test) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RecycleActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //return true;
}
```

This is the activity that crashes it:

```
package zeman.diktafonmev;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecycleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        /*
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        */

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        prepareMovieData();
    }

    private void prepareMovieData() {

        String end = ".mp3";
        String end2 = ".3gp";
        File myMp3Dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ZemanRecording/");
        ArrayList songs = new ArrayList();
        final File[] fileList = myMp3Dir.listFiles();
        if (fileList == null)
            return;
        for (File f : fileList) {
            if (!f.isDirectory()) //if file is browsing not directory
            {
                if (f.getName().toLowerCase().contains(end)) //if file with end is .mp3 is add to arraylist
                    songs.add(f.getName());
                if(f.getName().toLowerCase().contains(end2))
                    songs.add(f.getName());

                Movie movie = new Movie(f.getName(),  Boolean.toString(f.canRead()), "2015");
                movieList.add(movie);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface ClickListener {

        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private RecycleActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecycleActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

}
```

Basically I'm using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/).

I can run it separately, but I've only copied it and renamed some of it parts to work properly, because I already have an `activity_main`, so I renamed the one from that project to `activity_recycle.xml`.

I have added it to `AndroidManifest.xml` and my app does have the needed permissions.

```
ERROR
03-17 08:20:01.584 7290-7290/zeman.diktafonmev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: zeman.diktafonmev, PID: 7290
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{zeman.diktafonmev/zeman.diktafonmev.RecycleActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001e
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001e
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2598)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1049)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at zeman.diktafonmev.RecycleActivity.onCreate(RecycleActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_recycle"
    tools:context=".RecycleActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how my project looks like - does the (land) maybe affect it? I have tried starting the activity in landscape mode as well and it still crashes.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `movieList = = empty` and   `prepareMovieData();` before `setAdapter`

Comment: There is a problem in your xml file. Resolve it

Comment: Please include the `content_main.xml`.

Comment: Included content_main.xml, will try to find out the error. I am new to Android and have been spending 2 hours with this to no avail.

Comment: Comment out everything under `setContentView(R.layout.content_main);` in the `onCreate()` method. If it still crashes, it must be your layout. Also, does it still crash if you extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity `?

Comment: @Ricky It still crashes, so it is the layout. Good idea, I haven't thought of this way of checking for error. Still crashes even if I extend `Activity`.

Comment: @kapatikojoces It may (but shouldn't) be the (land) issue, but maybe it's worth trying, again, to uncomment everything in `onCreate()` and instead switch the `setContentView(R.layout.content_main);` to one of your other layouts which you know work, or don't have "(land)". If that works, it seems your activity is searching for a layout within a specific subfolder or size that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, if you haven't, do a clean/rebuild in case your layout contains an error. I've seen this problem before when making a change in the layout, even if it's nothing like an empty space, saving the layout and cleaning/rebuilding fixes the issue.

Comment: @Ricky, it does work with the other activity, such as activity_about.xml, but still won't work with the content_main.xml. I tried rebuilding and clean project, still nothing :( Maybe I should try another tutorial haha, thanks anyway, tomorrow is an another day for this problem at work :)

Comment: I'd get rid of these two lines  `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_recycle"` and `tools:context=".RecycleActivity`. If that doesn't work, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this layout file `(R.layout.content_main)`?

You are getting this error `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:` at line 27 (in the `onCreate()` method).

If you do have that file, then there probably is some bug in how the xml is set up over there.
Please share that xml file if you have it.

Comment: Added content_main.xml to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported your R in the RecycleActivity ? I do not see zeman.diktafonmev.R anywhere in the imports.

Also you may try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Answer (score -1):

remove the line `tools:showIn` from your XML

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, although more detailed answer would be more beneficial for the readers.

Comment: this will not cause a layout inflate error. the tools: namespace is only for android studio

Comment: @Shmuel why will that not create an issue? Because he is creating a cyclic dependency in his XML. His XML says " show content_main.xml inside content_main.xml"